# Magento get Last login

Tags: php, session, magento, authentication

How can I get last login details in Magento, as I am not getting anything using this code:

```
->joinTable('log/customer', 'customer_id=entity_id', array('logout_at'));
```

Comment: can you provide more information on where you are trying to call this code from, what the purpose is, what object you are calling the Join on?

Answer (score 1):

Try using left join instead

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('lc' => 'log_customer'), 'e.customer_id = lc.customer_id', array('logout_at' => 'logout_at'));

e.customer_id may in this case be main_table.customer_id
```

or

```
e.entity_id may in this case be main_table.entity_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet to get the logged in customer:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```